# Poweshell, Namespaces, and Variable Declaration

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I'm making some Powershell routines that automate tasks for Windows 10, Firewall, Services, and Task Scheduler.

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Powershell 7.1.2 x64

I declare variables using their object declaration exposed by their namespaces, this works quite well for functions operating on Windows Services. As follows:

```
using namespace System
using namespace System.ServiceProcess  # ServiceController exposure
```

Calling the System.ServiceProcess objects/library, exposes ServiceController object, so that I can declare variable or function returns as such.

```
[ServiceController] $WmplayerNetSrv = (Get-Service -Name "WMPNetworkSvc" -ErrorAction Stop)
```

This allows me to know exactly what a variable is, and enables a better intellisense list when referencing the variable.

All is well until I construct functions for the Windows 10 Firewall.

```
using namespace System
using namespace Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure #.CimInstance exposure
using namespace Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#root/standardcimv2    # /MSFT_NetFirewallRule exposure
```

I know variables in Powershell need not be declared, but I really want to do so.

I've tried:

```
using namespace Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#root/standardcimv2
[MSFT_NetFirewallRule] $WinFwRule = (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "RULE_NAME" -ErrorAction Stop)
```

Doesn't work, complains it can't find, MSFT_NetFirewallRule, type.

```
using namespace Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance
[#root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule] $WinFwRule = (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "RULE_NAME" -ErrorAction Stop)
```

Doesn't work, complains about the #, and the /, I'm sure the type wouldn't work too.

```
[Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule] $WinFwRule = (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "RULE_NAME" -ErrorAction Stop)
```

Doesn't work, complains it can't find, MSFT_NetFirewallRule, type.

So my questions are, how can I declare a variable as, [MSFT_NetFirewallRule]? Is this possible? I know I can fall back on [object[]], or not declare it.

Thanks and regards,

-njc

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot. Be aware that `Get-NetFirewallRule` may return an array. If you need to validate cim type, you can declare a `[CimInstance[]] $result` variable array, then test his type with `$result[0].CimClass.CimClassName -eq 'MSFT_NetFirewallRule'` (first, be sure that `$result` has a value ;) )

Comment: @CFou Thanks CFou, Get-NetFirewallRule does return an array, specifically [Object[]]. I'll work with that.

Comment: As I said `Get-NetFirewallRule` may return an array, not is returning an array, depending of the rule name (some are present multiple times for different connection profiles or other various reasons) - try this `Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Connect to a Network Projector (TCP-In)"` you will get an array. Whatever it is returning an array or not, you can declare your variable as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is probably because you're mixing up CIM classes with dotnet classes (i.e. types in the dotnet type system).

`MSFT_NetFirewallRule` is a CIM class (see [MSFT_NetFirewallRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/jj676843(v=vs.85))) and not a type from the dotnet type system, and as far as PowerShell is concerned your firewall rule is just a dotnet object of type `CimInstance` with a string property called `CimClass` that happens to have the value `Root/StandardCimv2:MSFT_NetFirewallRule`.

Your code should work if you do this:

```
[CimInstance] $WinFwRule = (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "RULE_NAME" -ErrorAction Stop)
```

but that's about as specific as you can be with your types.

Comment: thanks mclayton, that clarifies it for me. I've learnt something new today.